# How can I reference the sheet immediately to the left/right?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to reference the same cell, on the sheet immediately to the right, in a formula. Is there a way to do that? Is the sheets' order something we have access to from formulas?

I was hoping the [`ADDRESS` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en) would allow for relative sheet references, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: I do no think there is a formula to access the spreadsheet or sheet. You may need a script or a [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: You need `OFFSET()` function.

Comment: @idfurw Consider posting it as an answer. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer.

Comment: @player0 Why? What difference would a sheet make in this question?

Comment: @Harun24hr OP is not asking for a formula to reference to the right cell on the same sheet, but the same cell of the sheet "next" (right) to the current sheet.

Comment: @TheMaster because the question is low quality and while OP is aware of https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273 OP did not include whats the endgame. at this point this question has multiple answers but none or only one will work for OP. sheet would at least show the STRUCTURE of dataset and maybe some failed attempts. then based on sheet and sheet's locale a definitive formula could be crafted

Comment: @player0 Thank you for the response. I disagree though. Not every question should be about some kind of data manipulation to achieve some data structure goal. I think getting the "sheet to the right" through formula is the goal and that's the endgame in and of itself. And that's perfectly fine. While the answer is probably "no", that is a good answer in and of itself. And if there's a formula, that can do it and if someone can find it, that would be a great answer.

Comment: Yes, it is tempting to give the OP the `Y` they ask for. It seems evident in this case that there would be much better ways to solve the `X`, but it is tiring to probe the OP to find what `X` is. A sample spreadsheet usually lets contributors get to `X` much more easily than endless interrogation.

Comment: @dou But you're assuming it's a XY problem and that's only because Y is hard/impossible. We are not a support forum, but a Q/A site. We answer the question asked, and not who asked the question or what their hidden goal is or if there even is a hidden goal.We should evaluate whether question is useful for future viewers and answerable, if so answer it.If not, down/close vote if necessary and move on. But,using spreadsheets as alternative for direct discussion in comments would be bad, as people searching for Y would now be left with solution for X, which may not be the X related to their Y

Comment: In my experience it is a very typical flow that the OP is not happy with the solution they get for `Y` and therefore edit their question to get a solution for `Z`, often through several iterative steps to finally arrive at `X`, with the end result that questions get long and poorly formed, while answers address a question that differs from the final edited question. Alternatively, they post their `Z` and `X` in comments, with the result that answers get edited and no longer answer `Y`. SO is not a support forum, but as you know, the grand majority of first-time askers fail to get that.

Comment: @doubleunary Such edits should be immediately rolled back. If a answer  that addresses a problem has been posted,  and OP wants `Z`, they should be guided to make a new question for `Z`, not edit their question. In this specific case, OP is not a  first timer, knows what he's asking for, with research. Even if it is a `XY` problem, I think he can be easily persuaded to make a new question for `X`

Comment: Hmm... my recollection is that question rollback is only recommended if there is at least one answer with a vote. I see that there's a vote below now, so guess that this question can now be considered to be in its final form. We will see if the OP is happy with what they got. There is in my opinion no evidence for any substantive [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193) in the question.

Comment: @doubleunary I'm sure rollback is recommended, if the goal post substantially changes, regardless of whether the answer has votes. Compared to most questions in this tag, to me,  searching the documentation and linking one of the related  function is great research :)

Comment: @doubleunary Meta agrees. There's no one vote rule. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332863 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412228/ ``Generally such actions are frowned upon. Questions can be edited to add more context, or even correct the goal posts based on the comments (such as in the aforementioned XY Problem scenario), but this should certainly not be done after answers are received``

Comment: Thanks. I think we are done here.

Comment: It seems my question has sparked quite a debate there! When posting this, as always, I first did a couple Google searches, found no satisfying answer that way, then I asked the question in a general way, so that the answers can be useful to another person in the future (as @TheMaster intuited). As a daily user of this website myself, to get help from existing questions/answers, I always strive to make the types of contributions that I like to see from others, and I hope to achieve that at least a little bit. If not, I hope to get better with time. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for a reference to the cell at the same location as the current cell in another sheet. A *reference* to a cell is different from the *value* in that cell.

You can use `indirect()` and `address()` to get a reference to a cell in another sheet but only if you have the name of that other sheet. To get the sheet name, you will need to get a list of all sheet names, in the order they appear in the tab bar, and use `match()` together with `offset()` or `index()` to get a sheet name based on the name of the current sheet. For that, you will need [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) such as [SheetName() and SheetNames()](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95595167).

Since a custom function will be required in any case, it would perhaps be simpler to settle for the *value* in a cell rather than obtaining a *reference* to that cell. To do that, use a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) like this:

```js
/**
* Gets the value of the cell at the same location in the sheet
* immediately to the right of the active sheet in the tab bar.
*
* @param {-1} how_many_sheets_to_offset An integer that specifies a sheet to the left (negative) or right (positive) of the current sheet.
* @customfunction
*/
function ValueInTheCellAtTheSameLocationInTheSheetAtOffset(how_many_sheets_to_offset = 1) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[ss.getActiveSheet().getIndex() - 1 + how_many_sheets_to_offset];
  if (!sheet) {
    throw new Error(`There is no sheet that would be ${how_many_sheets_to_offset} steps from this sheet in that tab bar.`);
  }
  return sheet.getRange(ss.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()).getValue();
}
```

Note that all of the custom functions mentioned above will require additional parameters in the event you need to avoid [memoization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155888/269219) effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping I could stay in the realm of formulas and not get into functions, but if it is not possible, then I can see that this is the way to go. Regarding references vs values, I see the difference, I asked for the reference as a means to get to the value (I guess it was kind of obvious as I see that you've answered about that).

Comment: I'm wondering why there isn't a formula to get all sheet names in order, as you described. Either it just hasn't been implemented yet or there's a principle that makes in not a good idea to implement (I'm thinking it's the latter). I'll have to search more about it later, maybe it has already been suggested as a feature and has been rejected by the devs, giving us a reason.